# Rewrite Alternative use php instead of htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using a single index.php using switch...

My `.htaccess` is currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Usually I would settle for this option but it will just end up in conflicts down the track with other stuff how can I replicate this in php taking it off Apache.

By the file format above the `https://example.com/index.php?page=about` turns each case into `https://example.com/about`.

I can't find a simple guidance and how to achieve this in PHP and I know it is possible.

Comment: Possible I'm tired. But i have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to do the rewrite with PHP instead of using htaccess

Comment: What about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 0):

It is defenitly not possible. At some point you have to tell your webserver what to do with the request, it cannot guess by itself that you are running a php script.

A best practise for web applications is to map every request to your `index.php` (unless the file or directory exists) and then you can evaluate and route the request within your application on your behalf, e.g. something like this (from [laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You must not necessarily do this in you `.htaccess`, you could also put this in you [vhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) config or theoretically also in your [httpd.conf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html).

I can't see how this could end up in any conflicts, maybe you can explain your concerns regarding this a little bit more.

Comment: Not best, just common. It's half the reason WordPress has so many exploits and they're hard to clean up because they add more backdoors.

Comment: you're probably right, since I don't work with wordpress I'm not aware if there are any pitfalls with this solution. updated my answer.